# WCF Callback service Subscribe\Unsubscribe

Tags: c#, wcf, notsupportedexception

I trying to understand how to work with callbacks of WCF. I was create next interfaces:

```
public interface INotifierCallback : IEquatable<INotifierCallback>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Send notification.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notification">Notification.</param>
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SendNotificationBack(string notification);
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://MyWCFLearning.com/NorthwindCallbackService",
    CallbackContract = typeof(INotifierCallback))]
public interface INorthwindCallbackService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribe to notifications.
    /// </summary>
    [OperationContract]
    void Subscribe();

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribe from notifications.
    /// </summary>
    [OperationContract]
    void Unsubscribe();

    /// <summary>
    /// Send notification.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notification">Notification.</param>
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SendNotification(string notification);
}
```

I implement this interface by the next way:

```
public class NorthwindCallbackService : INorthwindCallbackService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Callbacks to clients.
        /// </summary>
        protected static IDictionary<INotifierCallback, byte> mCallbacks { get; set; }

        static NorthwindCallbackService()
        {
            NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks = new ConcurrentDictionary<INotifierCallback, byte>();
        }

        public void Subscribe()
        {
            INotifierCallback callbackForClient;

            callbackForClient = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<INotifierCallback>();
            if (NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.ContainsKey(callbackForClient) == false)
            {
                NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.Add(callbackForClient, default(byte));
            }
        }

        public void Unsubscribe()
        {
            INotifierCallback callbackForClient;

            callbackForClient = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<INotifierCallback>();
            if (NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.ContainsKey(callbackForClient))
            {
                NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.Remove(callbackForClient);
            }
        }

        public void SendNotification(string notification)
        {
            foreach (var currentCallback in NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks)
            {
                try
                {
                    currentCallback.Key.SendNotificationBack(notification);
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    //TODO: When client of NorthwindCallbackService call Dispose() method, we should remove callback of him from NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks, but I do not know how to make it.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I create UnitTest project where I added next method for test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SubscribeAndUnsubscribeTest()
{
    INorthwindCallbackServiceCallback callbackHandler;
    InstanceContext instanceContext;

    callbackHandler = new FakeINorthwindCallbackServiceCallback();
    instanceContext = new InstanceContext(callbackHandler);

    using (var callbackServiceClient = new NorthwindCallbackServiceClient(instanceContext))
    {
        callbackServiceClient.Subscribe();
        callbackServiceClient.Unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

And I have NotSupportedException for Equals method when execute next line of WCF service:

```
if (NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.ContainsKey(callbackForClient))
```

I understand that reason of this problem is not implemented IEquatable, but how to implement it on server side, and what is the best way to use callbacks?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is about the last part of the question:

> what is the best way to use callbacks?

You got the idea covered, but why are you not using the `byte` value of the `ConcurrentDictionary`? First of all, there is no 'best way'. But I propose to change the `ConcurrentDictionary` in such a way that you can store a client id together with the callback info into the `ConcurrentDictionary` so you can query easier and you can store more info about the client:

```
public class NorthwindCallbackService : INorthwindCallbackService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Callbacks to clients.
    /// </summary>
    protected static IDictionary<Guid, INotifierCallback> mCallbacks { get; set; }

    static NorthwindCallbackService()
    {
        NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, INotifierCallback>();
    }

    public void Subscribe(Guid clientId)
    {
        INotifierCallback callbackForClient;

        callbackForClient = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<INotifierCallback>();
        if (NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.ContainsKey(clientId) == false)
        {
            NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.Add(clientId, callbackForClient);
        }
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Guid clientId)
    {
        INotifierCallback callbackForClient;

        callbackForClient = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<INotifierCallback>();
        if (NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.ContainsKey(clientId))
        {
            NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks.Remove(clientId);
        }
    }

    public void SendNotification(string notification)
    {
        foreach (var currentCallback in NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks)
        {
            try
            {
                currentCallback.Value.SendNotificationBack(notification);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                //TODO: When client of NorthwindCallbackService call Dispose() method, we should remove callback of him from NorthwindCallbackService.mCallbacks, but I do not know how to make it.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now since you can identify the clients you can also send notifications to specific clients if you extend the `SendNotification` method with a `Guid` parameter.

You could even replace the `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, INotifierCallback>` with an instance of a custom class that contains more information about the client like Id, type of notifications it likes to receive, ip-address or whatever you want using a `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ClientCallbackInfo>` construct:

```
public class ClientCallbackInfo
{
    public INotifierCallback Callback { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherClientInfo { get; set; } 
}
```